# Creating a clickable tag that contains different elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

## Elements within clickable h2

### Introduction

I am creating a one-line menu in html. I have 3 options that work in a really similar way. The problem is that the one that has the html right, looks like it can fail more easily. I put the 3 examples here. I am looking for reliable, browser-compatible menu. The third option uses javascript so I don't really love it.

The menu has to be 100% width, within a gray rectangle and has to have some text at left and some at right. The entire menu has to be clickable with only one hyperlink. This is [what I have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far:

### Implemented examples

A link to see them all working is [here](http://newfutureuniversity.org/test/hblock.php) (DISCLAIMER: yes, it is my own webpage). If you don't feel like clicking there, here's an image of how they look in the same order as the options:

[image: Showing 3 current alternatives]

### Option 1.

This one is no html compliant, but I've found is the one more logical, it behaves better in general and it's not likely to give many troubles:

```
<a href="http://newfutureuniversity.org/test/hblock.php">
  <h2 style="width:100%; height:100%; border: 1px solid #AAA; padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px; background-color: #EEE;">
    Hello world
    <span style="margin: 6px; color:gray; font-size: 15px; float:right; ">
      Right text
    </span>
  </h2>
</a>
```

### Option 2.

This one is html compliant, but I just hate to center things using pixels. I feel like it will break really easily. Besides, the text in the right is not fully clickable:

```
<h2 style="border: 1px solid #AAA; padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px; background-color: #EEE;">
  <a href="http://newfutureuniversity.org/test/hblock.php" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:block;">
    Hello world
  </a>
  <span style="position: relative; right: 6px; top:-23px; color:gray; font-size: 15px; float:right; ">
    Right text
  </span>
</h2>
```

### Option 3.

This one uses javascript. I prefer not to bloat every menu like this one with javascript and to use html/css is available, but this is another option. It doesn't get the color that regular links do.

```
<h2 onclick="location.href='http://newfutureuniversity.org/test/hblock.php';" style="cursor:pointer; display: block; width:100%; height:100%; border: 1px solid #AAA; padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px; background-color: #EEE;">
  Hello world
  <span style="margin: 6px; color:gray; font-size: 15px; float:right; ">
    Right text
  </span>
</h2>
```

### Question

**Which one do is more browser compatible and unlikely to break? Do you have any other recommendation or improvement? Any feedback will be appreciated**

PS, all the inline CSS will be put apart in a different css sheet.

Comment: Please post demos to a demo-site, that way the question retains its usefulness in future and isn't prone to being...deprecated once you've corrected/fixed your code. Also, this question *seems* like you're inviting opinion, rather than concrete/potentially objectively-correct 'answers.' What's the problem that you're *having*, *why* do you think the correct-HTML approach is more likely to break? Under what circumstances?

Comment: I didn't see much point in using a demo-site as my page is in really early development so I am not promoting it, but other people might think otherwise. I will put future code in demo sites.
I don't like completely any of the 3 alternatives, so instead of saying, 'how do I do this?' and not put anything, I thought that posting my approaches is better.
I am not having currently any problem, but I want to prevent having any. Same as I do with mysql injection.
Because it is adjusted to the pixel while the rest of the page is adjusted to %. The text itself is positioned with negative margin...

Comment: Option 2. is better way for browser compatibility, i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that the better approach is to reorganise your HTML, to the following:

```
<h2>
    <a href="http://newfutureuniversity.org/test/hblock.php">Hello world<span>Right text</span></a>
</h2>​
```

And then use the following CSS:

```
a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.2em;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #aaa;
}

a span {
    color: #000;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kazZu/1/).

The validity of this depends on the elements you want to ultimately place within the `h2` tag to remain clickable, though. Under HTML5 it's valid to nest block-level elements within an `a` tag, under HTML4, though, while it still seems to work it's *not* considered valid, according to the doctype.

But, for the posted requirements this seems to work; albeit it does require the restructuring of your HTML, which may not be possible. However:

- it *is* valid HTML,
- it's resistant to breaking (unless the content of the `span` exceeds a given width,
- it doesn't rely on arbitrary `px` adjustments (albeit it does use `padding` to vertically centre the resized text within the `a`),
- it doesn't require JavaScript

---

**Edited** to amend the CSS a little, to account for the potential for the right-floated text to become large enough to overflow to the next line, by simply adding `overflow: hidden` to the `a` element's CSS:

```
a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.2em;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #aaa;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kazZu/2/).

You could also, of course, add a `max-width` to the `span`:

```
a span {
    color: #000;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    max-width: 80%;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kazZu/3/).

Comment: Just perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know that bit about HTML5 though, thank you for both.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David Thomas on his mark up. Although I would alter the css slightly in order to make it more robust. If you resize your browser so that the right span gets pushed below the left text (make the browser smaller), then you'll see that the clearing properties that I have applied mean the a stays wrapped around the span rather than allowing the span to move outside of the a area.

**HTML:**

```
<h2 class="item ">
    <a href="#" >Loads of left left Left Text<span>Right Text lots more</span></a>
</h2>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item a {
    zoom:1;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background: grey;
    display: block;
}
.item a:before,
.item a:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.item a:after {
    clear:both;
}
.item span {
    background: green;
    float: right;
}
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Vc3DA/